# Where is Chromium installed?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, chromium

How can I execute the Chromium browser with a preset url from the command line with a url?

I'm unsure as using the following command:

```
Chromium.sh google.com
```

returns error

> Chromium not found

Where the apps are installed on Pi stretch desktop ?

Comment: use `chromium-browser` (no caps and no `.sh`)

Comment: You can find its location via `which chromium-browser`

Comment: @Dirk If you don't make an answer this question will hang for months ;) Or another one will answer it, but it's yours.

Answer (score 2):

The correct name is `chromium-browser` (no capitals and no '.sh') so the command would be

```
chromium-browser google.com
```